# Groupby data in Pandas to label my pie chart

Tags: python, pandas, database, group-by, data-analysis

I have using groupby in Pandas,

```
df_0 = df_find_quality_und.groupby("user score").size()
df_0
```

and get this output;

```
Output:
user score
3.0    14
7.0     2
7.1     1
7.2     2
7.3     1
7.5     1
7.7     1
7.8     2
7.9     1
8.0     1
8.1     2
8.3     1
8.7     1
dtype: int64
```

> The right side is the frequency of the the data.

Then, I want to plot this data into a pie-chart. But I don't know how to take the left data only to become the labels of my pie-chart. Hence, I write it manually like this;

```
user_sc_und = [3.0,7.0,7.1,7.2,7.3,7.5,7.7,7.8,7.9,8.0,8.1,8.3,8.7]
user_sc_und_1 = df_find_quality_und.groupby("user score")
plot = plt.pie(df_0, labels=user_sc_und)
```

The pie-chart was well shown in the output with the label. But, I don't want to write the labels manually every time.. Can anyone help me on how to label the pie-chart by taking the groupby data on the **left** side?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pandas allows you to plot pie chart:

```
df_0 = df_find_quality_und.groupby("user score").size()
df_0.plot.pie(autopct="%.2f",figsize=(10,10))
```

output:

[image]

Comment: This works successfully. Plus, it has the percentage label too! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

The labels are actually the index of the groupby sizes object, so, you can try:

```
plot = plt.pie(df_0, labels=df_0.index)
```

Comment: Already tried and works really well. Thank you so much!